# how to use auto numbered class into click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML on a webpage multiple times which is generated by PHP.

```
<a href="#" class="generate">generate</a><div class="selectArea selectBox"></div>
```

Now I use this code to give each div their own individual classes

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".selectArea").each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass("selectBox" + (i+1));
  });
});
```

But now I need to change this:

```
$(".selectBox").html($select);
```

which is inside a click function

```
$(document).on('click', '.generate', function () {
```

So that it also works with (i+1).

## what i try to achieve

The above code is part of a entire project. In this project I got a selectbox with options generated from several inputs. In the `.html` I add this selectbox to the div. But right now it is added to all the divs on the page instead of just one.

Comment: jQuery's *attribute-starts-with-selector* should work - [`jQuery( "[attribute^='value']" )`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: How would I change this `$(".selectBox").html($select);` to work with your suggestion?

Comment: Can you write complete `.click()` function?

Comment: yeah sure post it in a minute

Comment: is the `.generate` anchor element right before `.selectBox` div?

Comment: yes it is. but as the div it is also multiple times on the same page. can i upload a picture or something in stack?

Comment: `$("[class^='selectBox']").html()` This is the only thing that will work.

Comment: @KinshukLahiri I tried your solution but it does fire the alert so that is working but it does not show the selectbox. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the `.generate` element is right before `.selectBox` div, then instead of:

```
$(".selectBox").html($select);
```

use jQuery's [**`.next()`**](https://api.jquery.com/next/):

```
$(this).next('.selectArea').html($select);
```

Comment: Yes that worked nicely. Still giving me other issues would you mind helping me with that in a chat? Seeing your score you know a lot more about this stuff then I do ;-)

Comment: Depends on the amount of *issues* ;)

Comment: Alright so when I click generate it shows the list. But when I press save the selectboxes are gone again. So I basically need it to generate the list on load except if a user already changed it. 

If this removes the entire generate link part it would be even better. I tried doing it in doc. ready but then every time the page refreshes all lists where regenerated.

Comment: @purple11111 Post your save's code in the question.

Comment: alright let me put the entire file in the question. also it is a joomla custom field inside a repeatable subform. will mention that also in the question.

Comment: I wished I could do a fiddle for this but it is inside joomla and to many systems which i have no clue to mimic in fiddle.

Comment: instead of editing this question, open another one. It's different issue and the code. Make sure you include all (JS and HTML) code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: :-( not allowed to post within 90 minutes. I will post as soon as I am allowed and share the link with you. Thank you very much for helping me out same goes for Kinshuk.

Comment: @ArturFilipiak The new question can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40270931/on-load-generate-selectbox-except-if-user-already-made-a-selection-joomla-subfo
It has all the info that I could think of init.

Answer (score 0):

I think that each div is being given the same class so all divs will be affected.

Declare i outside of your function so it is global.  Also give it a better name.

Something like this

```
var select_box_count = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".selectArea").each(function() {
    select_box_count ++;
    $(this).addClass("selectBox" + (select_box_count+1));
  });
});
```

Comment: No every div has its own number that part works fine. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference that with an id

In the div that you only want that

```
$('#id').html($select);
```

Or just using a selector like

```
$('.selectBox:first-child').html($select);
```

Or just

```
$(".selectBox")[number element].html($select);
```

Comment: I am not trying to pick just one I need to have a solution like the one Artur gave so it works dynamically for all of them. So I can't use the first and last one. But the second one does work partially it gives the alert but it does not show the selectbox.